# How to configure "body" parameter to input JSON data in Django Rest Swagger UI for POST method?

Tags: django, post, swagger

I'm using django-rest-swagger 2.1.2 and python 2.7. In Swagger UI, for a post method, how can I configure the UI so that there is a body parameter for me to input JSON data along with other types of parameters, such as path? Thanks.

Comment: isn't there already a body text input in post http methods in swagger-ui?

Comment: Can you let me know which file? When I brought up the UI, for POST method, I don't see any textarea that allows me to input JSON data. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Django Swagger UI shows methods that are implemented by your Viewsets, for eg: `ModelViewSet` supports following methods `create()`, `retrieve()`, `update()`,
    `partial_update()`, `destroy()` and `list()`.

So Swagger will show all methods. Make sure whatever viewset your are using, implement methods that you want to see on UI.